# File object methods write() or writelines() start writing at unexpected position in buffer [Python 3.4.3]

Tags: python, file-io, seek

Suppose I want to change the first two characters of the second line of the text file `text_file` to `XX`.

Say `text_file` has contents:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I wrote the following script to accomplish the task:

```
f = open('text_file', 'r+')
f.readline()
f.write('XX')
f.close() # this flushes changes to disk implicitly
```

When I run this code in Python 2.7.9, this works fine, altering `text_file` so that it becomes:

```
line1
XXne2
line3
```

However, when I run it in Python 3.4.3, `text_file` ends up having these contents:

```
line1
line2
line3
XX
```

Now, if I alter the code like this:

```
f = open('text_file', 'r+')
f.readline()
f.seek(f.tell()) # shouldn't this be doing nothing?
f.write('XX')
f.close() # this flushes changes to disk implicitly
```

And run it in Python 3.4.3, the results are as desired.

I seriously don't understand what's going on here: why does `write()` start writing at that unexpected position[*]? And seeking to the current position isn't supposed to be changing anything, right?

Hope somebody can shed some light on this for me, thanks!

**UPDATE**: It's probably worth mentioning the OS I'm using. It's Xubuntu 15.04, Linux kernel 3.19.

**UPDATE 2**: As suggested by @cdarke, opening in binary mode `rb+` (and accordingly writing binary strings) makes the script work in Python 3.4.3 without the use of `seek` as I did above. Why does this work, and not my original way?

(*): **NOTE**: That it starts writing at the end of the buffer is a matter of coincidence. I know this because the actual text file I'm working with is much larger, and there it didn't start writing at the end of the buffer.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on OS X (2.7.10 and 3.5).  Try opening in binary mode.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks for checking and for your suggestion. Changing open mode to `rb+` does the trick. Any idea why this makes a difference and why text mode does not work?

Comment: The documentation implies that what you are trying is undefined, although it doesn't actually directly show your example:  "*In text files (those opened without a b in the mode string), only seeks relative to the beginning of the file are allowed (the exception being seeking to the very file end with seek(0, 2)) and the only valid offset values are those returned from the f.tell(), or zero. Any other offset value produces undefined behaviour.*".  In https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: It was that para that made me suggest binary access, but I could not test it because it worked for me - hence only a comment and not an answer.    I have also had to use the `f.seek(f.tell())` trick with EOF operations (like emulating `tail -f`).

Comment: @cdarke I've read that part of the documentation, but I fail to see what your citation has to do with my problem. I don't call `seek` anywhere in the original problem, so how can its behavioral differences between binary and text mode be relevant to the problem?

Comment: I agree that it does not show your exact issue, but what it implies is that the file position is undefined in text mode (other than the documented exceptions).  When reading and writing to the same file it is usual to use random access and binary mode, since text mode is not suitable for random access.  So I am saying that this is expected behaviour, however I agree that it would be better if it was explicitly documented.