# Is it possible to change (update) the entries of a numpy array already saved in a .npy file? How?

Tags: python, numpy

I saved a numpy array in .npy format on disk I load it using np.load() but I don't know how to save on the disk the changes I made .

Comment: Use the save [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)

Comment: You just have to save the array again; there's no overwrite of the existing saved file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options you could explore. The first is if you know the position of the change in the file, you can:

```
file = open("path/to/file", "rb+")
file.seek(position)
file.seek(file.tell()). # There seems to be a bug in python which requires you to do this
file.write("new information") # Overwriting contents
```

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/783843/4782513) why `file.seek(file.tell())`

The second is to save the modified array itself

```
myarray = np.load("/path/to/my.npy")
myarray[10] = 50.0 # Any new value
np.save("/path/to/my.npy", myarray)
```

Comment: A `npy` file is a binary file, not text.  The file contains a byte image of the data buffer, but we don't normally know where a particular element occurs.

Comment: @hpaulj, edited answer now to reflect that `npy` is a binary file. Indeed it is difficult to know where a particular element occurs but the answer also includes the situation when it is known.

Comment: Thank you, newkid. I used np.save() to create the .npy file, but I didn't think to use it also to save on the disk changes I made. It is so obvious now. Thanks again, it is very appreciated