# Weird file seeking behaviour

Tags: python

With respect to two interactions below, I'd expect the same file output by both, but the second one writes at the end of the file. The only difference is a read statement AFTER the write, I don't understand what's happening. What am I missing?

Expected behavior:

```
>>> f = open("test.txt","w+")
>>> f.write('0123456789')
10
>>> f.seek(0)
0
>>> f.read(3)
'012'
>>> f.seek(0,1)
3
>>> f.write('XX')
2
>>> f.seek(0)
0
>>> f.read()
'012XX56789'
>>> f.close()
```

Unexpected behavior:

```
>>> f = open("test.txt","w+")
>>> f.write('0123456789')
10
>>> f.seek(0)
0
>>> f.read(3)
'012'
>>> f.seek(0,1)
3
>>> f.write('XX')
2
>>> f.read(2)
'34'
>>> f.seek(0)
0
>>> f.read()
'0123456789XX'
>>> f.close()
```

As you can see `XX` was written **after** the whole line, while I was at position 3 when writing these characters.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Did the file exist before the first interaction? Did it exist before the second interaction? The w+ argument means write and append to the file.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this strange behaviour with python 3.6.5, both with a previously existing file and a non-existing file... seems like a python bug to me.

Comment: Looks like a buffering-related bug to me. Adding `f.flush()` after the `write('XX')` makes it work as expected.

Comment: Same problem with your second code. I suspected that there could be something related to text mode and tried it in binary mode: it works as expected in this case.

Comment: Answer on [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/783843/9609843) has something interesting info: it contains a [link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2005-August/029886.html) where it is stated that _the effect of mixing reads with writes on a file open for update 
is entirely undefined unless a file-positioning operation occurs 
between them (for example, a seek())._

Comment: @saniash Inserting `f.seek(0,1)` between the write and the read gives the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

What happened was that the `write` was buffered, and the intervening `read` advanced the underlying file position to the end of the file (since it’s small) before the write was committed (flushed).  If what follows the write is a `seek`, the write buffer is committed (to the right place) before actually seeking.  This approach avoids overhead on every read to check for pending writes and has long been [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html).

Comment: You make it sound normal, but in my opinon is not. Buffering is supposed to be transparent, it shouldn't alter the program semantics, only performance. That 2nd sequence would normally play differently in another language, I think this is a Python implementation peculiarity. And I wasn't aware of it. Now that I know I'll be careful, still if you don't know it could be the source of nasty bugs.

Comment: @MarkusSteiner: Opening for update with buffering is considered to be a special case, and Python just defers to C for its semantics.  You’re welcome to disagree with the design decision, of course!